# Get curent link

Tags: javascript, php, html, macros

I have a php file that will load inside of  my partner sites as an inframe
http://dfomain.com/file.php

but i want his php file to get the link details where it loads:
for example it has been loaded inside of: http://demox.com/demotextlink
And with a simple tag me to place $$url$$.
Because inside of that php file i will have Javascript tag from ad network that asks for detailed macro  where the ad has been loaded.
so if some one can createan example php file or give codes would be so happy :)

Comment: No not exactly . The php file must get the current link where it has been loaded. Because insid eof that php file will be banner of 728x90 or other size form an ad network. They nee me place on source= something like $$url$$ so that will show on their platform on what url the banner ad has been loaded :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for! But if you wanna load the content of a file like "example.php".

You could use `AJAX` as a solution!

Here is a example where the script asks for a file and then loads the content with `innerHTML` in a `main` tag.

```
function GET_CONTENT() {

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('POST', 'EXAMPLE_FILE.php');

    req.addEventListener('load', function (e) {


        document.querySelector("main").innerHTML = e.target.response;


    });
    req.send();
}
```

**IF!**

If you wanna load content from another domain/server! Then you need to add this piece of code to avoid something like cross error....

Comment: No i need a php file that will just get the curent link where the banner ad has loaded. and to be able to insert that in banner tag something like command ##url## and when loaded it will give them the link also where was loaded :)

Answer (score 0):

The page http://demox.com/demotextlink loads an iframe located at http://dfomain.com/file.php.

Javascript won't let you access the parent document because it's not the same domain, for security reason.

So you can explicitly add the information you need via the query string, for instance :

```
<!-- http://demox.com/demotextlink -->
<iframe src="http://dfomain.com/file.php?from=http://demox.com/demotextlink"></iframe>
```

Or you can use the referer.

```
// http://dfomain.com/file.php
<script>
var from = "<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>";
</script>
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php for all variables made available by the server.